# iText Signature Verification Detail

Tags: itext, x509certificate, digital-signature

I am following this tutorial (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222) to get a PDF signed with my company's certificate.  I'm using iText 5.3.4 along with Bouncy Castle 1.47.  When I run it, the PDF gets signed fine, but it fails to verify.

Here's what I get on the text file that it outputs:

Signature name: third
Signature covers whole document: true
Document revision: 1 of 1
Subject: {cert info}
Revision modified: false
[com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.VerificationException: Certificate {cert info} failed:
 Cannot be verified against the KeyStore or the certificate chain]

My company's cert info is where you see the {cert info}.  To get more detail, I also added a method from of the iText white paper to check CRL and OCSP.  My output message in the console said it had a valid OCSP, but no CRL.

Is this causing the problem?  If not, is there a way to get more detail than "Cannot be verified against the KeyStore or the certificate chain" from the earlier error?

Comment: Call printStackTrace() for all VerificationException you get from CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(...) to print more details.

Comment: *My output message in the console said it had a valid OCSP, but no CRL* - for a single certificate you don't need both, either one suffices. That being said, please provide a sample PDF to reproduce your issue.